# Setting flash mode to off as default

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to set the camera flash mode in an UIImagePickerController to off, but I don't understand [the reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html). Here is my code:

```
- (void)getMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     sourceType] && [mediaTypes count] > 0) {
    NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController
                           availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
    mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
    UIImagePickerController *picker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice *device;
    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}}
```

I've tried setting picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff, but this results in an error. The reference page says that cameraDevice is a property. Does this mean that I need to create that property myself, or is it located somewhere? 'Cause the camera works if I don't do anything to the code, but with flash mode set to auto...

There is obviously something I haven't understood.  :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

replace `picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff`  with
`picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;`

Comment: Still getting a SIGABRT at that line :/

Comment: Of course, I had to write it after setting delegate to self... Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: just to check, your are running on 4.0 + version ?

Comment: please select as answer ,if it address the issue.